# jQuery/Ajax detect if child nodes exist

Tags: xml, ajax, jquery

Here is what I am looking into doing... I have not found anyone looking for this so I apologize if this is a duplicate that I have missed somewhere.

**Scenario**

Reading in an XML file. The names of the nodes can be dynamic (they don't always follow the same node names). For instance:

```
<course_title></course_title>
<course_subtitle></course_subtitle>
```

However, they can ALSO have nested nodes within them so it could be

```
<course_title>
    <course_prefix>
</course_title>
```

So with that, I need to be able to detect if in fact there IS a nested node or not. So what I am wondering is, is there a way to detect whether a node has nested children without manually going through the children using something like

```
$(xmlFile).children().children().children(); //not ideal if you dont know how nested something is
```

Comment: Why do you need to know if it has children? wouldn't you be iterating over them anyway? Iterating over 0 items iterates 0 times.

Comment: @KevinB Well, I am using the XML to determine the layout of an HTML form. So, in the example I provided, with that nested <course_prefix> I want to be able to place that nested node into a "nested" DIV that I end up creating...

Answer (score 3):

Check the length of the selector to see if it contains any elements :

```
$(xmlFile).children().length
```

or to check for specific nodeName :

```
$(xmlFile).find('course_prefix').length
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(node).hasChildNodes()) {
    // It has at least one child node
}
```